# Enumerate unique strings in list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Disclaimer: I'm not an experienced Python user.

I encountered a task and now I'm trying to figure out the most elegant way to do it in Python.

Here's the task itself: given a `list` of strings return a list of `int`s (each `int` from 0 to N - 1, where N is the number of unique strings in the list), where each int corresponds to a certain string from initial list. Same strings should be mapped to same numbers, different strings - to different numbers.

The first thing I came up with seems "a little bit" overcomplicated:

```
a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
map(lambda x: dict(map(lambda x: reversed(x), enumerate(set(a))))[x], a)
```

The result of code above:

```
[0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dict and list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
>>> d = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(set(a))}
>>> [d[item] for item in a]
[0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

To preserve order:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> d = { x:i for i, x in enumerate(y for y in a
                                       if y not in seen and not seen.add(y))}
>>> [d[item] for item in a]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```

The above dict comprehension is equivalent to:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> lis = []
for item in a:
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        lis.append(item)
...         
>>> lis
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(lis)}
```

Comment: +1 for second one, but don't you think it could a little bit hard to reed?

Comment: I think `{x:i for i, x in reverse(list(enumerate(a)))}` will allow you to preserve order

Comment: @Eric But for `c`, it'll return `3`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Whoops

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach with set could lead to errors if you want to preserve order of approach characters. Actually you can see it in your example - `'b'` got index `2` instead of `1`. If you want to keep order, you can use [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
>>> d = {x:i for i, x in enumerate(OrderedDict(izip(a, a)).values())}
>>> [d[x] for x in a]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: I'm not that worried about strings order, but that's an interesting feature, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Emphasis on readability, not speed: I would use the list `index` method with a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
>>> b = list(set(a))
>>> c = [b.index(x) for x in a]
>>> c
[0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: It seems to me that `index` would cause interpreter to go through `b` for each item in `a`, which is about O(n^2). I might be wrong, though. `dict`-based solutions should be (at least, I hope so) O(n) in average.

Comment: Indeed. I went for the most readable solution, without considering performance too much.

Answer (score 0):

First get the unique strings from the list and enumerate it, so you have a number (from 0 to N-1) for each string. then get this value for each of the strings, and put it in a list. here is how it is done, in one line:

```
a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
[{s:i for i, s in enumerate(set(a))}[s] for s in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a defaultdict and count iterator.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import count
>>> a = ["a","b","a","c","b","a"]
>>> x = defaultdict(count().next)
>>> [x[i] for i in a]
[0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```